# Requesting new Badge for people that submit edits that are rejected or rolledback

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I think we need a [molester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/molester) badge that indicated that someone has a certain number of suggested edits rejected or if they can unilaterally edit, has had a certain number of edits rolled back.

Comment: I don't think permanently flagging someone with Shame for edits is a good path. Everyone could evolve and change, keeping a trace of old bad behavior is not good IMO

Comment: Aren't badges for POSITIVE reinforcement? Except tumbleweed: the consolation badge

Comment: @Patrice and Peer-presure also ? I think it's enough

Comment: @Patrice I'm happy to have a badge even Jon Skeet doesnt have ^^

Comment: Peer-pressure is about one making decision themselves, what is proposed in this request is what others think about action of given account.

Comment: Wear your badges of shame on *the inside*

Comment: This was supposed to be a joke, right?  **Right?**

Comment: Still trying to find the witty connection between "molester" and "rejection".  Maybe you should have called it the "Geek" badge?  Or "Jr. Prom Date"?  Or was this a poke at the Necromancer badge post?

Comment: they are *molesting* the content. *Touching it in an improper way that causes harm.* I can't believe that things like this have to be spelled out. And yes the *Necormancer* badge post inspired this.

Comment: Oh!  It all makes sense now.  :o)

Comment: I like the idea, but I can see the potential for abuse. Angry with someone? Roll back some of their edits. Then say "hey, that user doesn't know how to edit, look!"  A way to make strict reviewers look like bad editors.

Comment: These people don't need badges - they need bans.

Answer (score 15):

No. Badges are supposed to be *rewards*, not indicators of wrong-doing. Even "consolation prize" badges like Tumbleweed and Peer-Pressure are not marks of shame. They represent things that can happen.

They are not meant to be a stigma.

Comment: What about "peer-presure" ?

Comment: @Tensibai what is bad about someone "self-moderating" by deleting a bad post? (unless I'm confusing my badges there)

Comment: @Tensibai: ... what about it? Badges are not the proper tool for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Tensibai You're rewarded with a badge for learning that you can delete questions/answers that turn out to be either a bad fit for the site, or wrong. Deletion is a good part of cleaning up the site, so it still fits. Tumbleweed is more an example of a badge that does not fit this statement.

Comment: I don't feel it's a cool reward. It tells others you deleted your own post wich was highly downvoted. I would be for the removal of this badge in fact.

Comment: @Tensibai are we discussing whether it's a cool reward or not, or whether is it to reinforce positive behavior? two different topics. It encourages people to help keep the site cleaner by removing their own bad content.

Comment: @Patrice The answer say the badges are rewards, I don't fell the peer presure badge is a reward, more a mark of shame you can't get rid of because you asked a bad Q one day.

Comment: @Tensibai I think we are all humans who accept that not everyone asks perfect questions everyday. I always associated "peer-pressure" to being "you decided to moderate your question after seeing its reception on stack, understanding that even if your question may help YOU, it's not a good fit for the site". I've always understood it as a "self-awareness" badge type-deal. I don't think ONE bad question is a mark on your record... but being able to understand the purpose of the site and keep it clean, even if the question COULD help you, is a sign of maturity and understanding of Stack's goals.

Comment: *Devil's advocate*: So in this case, a badge for someone stopping bad edits would be the same ? I.e: ratio of accepted edit versus rejected edit become positive after being negative for a while ? (after edit)

Comment: @Patrice I agree, but still those two badges are a dual sided blade at the end of the day. They mark permanently a point in time with a specific action. I feel they're not necessary at all. I obviously agree  badges should not stigmate people for actions

Comment: @Tensibai yes.... a specific action that no one would consider terrible.... There is a MAJOR difference between a badge going "you made a boo-boo once, but good job on correcting it for the betterment of everyone" (the action the badge focuses on isn't the boo-boo, but correcting it.... or we'd have badges for posting a -3 question), and this badge, which would be "you did terrible edits". Even a badge about "changing" behavior isn't the same. The peer pressure badge isn't "you've improved your question-asking skills", as this badge you just suggested would be.

Comment: @Patrice - `/"you did terrible edits"/"you did an extremely enormous amount of terrible edits"/g` - can be earned multiple times

Comment: @JarrodRoberson as a new father, I'd prefer not to be associated with "molester" multiple times ;) (even once, for that matters :P)